# BroadcastReceiver to notify when Bluetooth is connected

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I want to make a `BroadcastReceiver` that notifies me when the Bluetooth is *connected* to another device.

```
BroadcastReceiver bluetooth = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
};
```

and

```
    IntentFilter ff = new IntentFilter();
    ff.addAction(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(bluetooth, ff);
```

and AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

but when the device is connected, nothing happens, why?

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));

getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action))
        {
            // LOG - Connected
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action))
        {
            // LOG - Disconnected
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: There is. Try it or not, you can decide.

Comment: didn't work...however I must note that I'm trying that by connecting my device to my laptop Bluetooth, is that ACL ?